# add new language to telegram source code for android

Tags: java, android

I am try to add my local language to source code of telegram
I download source code from [github](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram)
Now i want to add new language to code

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please clarify where you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android apps typically store Strings in `string.xml` files. 
[Here](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/tree/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/res) you'll see a bunch of folders like `values-xy` (with country codes), they contain those files. Create you're own and translate the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Also, they're have an option to do that on following link if you wanna help them with

**Official Telegram**:

https://www.transifex.com/telegram/telegram/

You can see the translated languages by the way, if you are interested to do that for your own version(`Unofficial`), just follow the docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework

or exactly like @Ascorbin said.